# calling Python script with GPIO module over apache2 web server

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, apache-httpd, permissions

I have `test.py` file, and it contains GPIO module commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as G
import time

G.setmode(G.BCM)        
G.setup(18, G.OUT)
G.output(18, True)
time.sleep(3)
G.output(18, False)

G.cleanup()
```

I want to call this python script for execution when I press button on my web page. My `index.html` contains javascript to call `.py` for execution:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
    document.location="cgi-bin/test.py";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Raspberry Pi GPIO</h1>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="call .py" onclick="func()">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like problems are permissions, so when I click on the button, apache2 retrieves code 500 - Internal error. Execution of `test.py` from bash with `sudo` command works fine.

Is there any way to set these permissions, so the apache2 can successfully call python script that contains GPIO commands? Thanks

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3499/5538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are numerous ways.  If you google I'm sure you will find them.

However I don't think it'll be a worthwhile effort - if you wait a week or so there should be an update to the RPi.GPIO module to allow its use without requiring root privileges.

There are other Python modules.

My [pigpio Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) does not require Python to be run as root (it sends requests to a daemon which has the needed privileges).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import pigpio # abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

LED=18

pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to local Pi.

pi.set_mode(LED, pigpio.OUTPUT)

for i in range(10):
   pi.write(LED, 1)
   time.sleep(0.2)
   pi.write(LED, 0)
   time.sleep(0.2)

pi.stop() # Disconnect from local Pi.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give everyone the right to execute

```
sudo chmod 750 /path/to/cgi-bin/test.py
```

Comment: This command does not give everyone the right to execute. Only to group members and the owner.